# Spring Statemachine - implicit state transitions

Tags: spring, state-machine, spring-statemachine

Is it somehow possible to construct a statemachine where only the next state itself fires an event to invoke the next state transition? Like implicit transitions. I dont want to define them all externally i want to create something like a cascade.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want a "domino" like effect on state transitions (cascade transitions - so that the current state triggers the transition to the next state, which in turn triggers the transition to the next state and so on).

That's straight forward to do with SM actions.
Each SM Action has access to [`StateContext<State, Event>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/StateContext.html) from which you can retrieve the state machine instance and fire the next event:

```
//Domino Effect
void actionForS1(StateContext<State, Event> context) {
  //do actions
  Message transitionToS2 = MessageBuilder.withPayload(...).build();
  context.getStateMachine().sendEvent(transitionToS2);
}

void actionForS2(StateContext<State, Event> context) {
  //do actions
  Message transitionToS3 = MessageBuilder.withPayload(...).build();
  context.getStateMachine().sendEvent(transitionToS3);
}
```